# Access Unity Module variables from external script in VueJS

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine, vue.js, typeerror

I am making trying to embed a Unity build into a VueJS component. The Unity project is made in 4.0, which is too bad because it means I can't use: https://github.com/votetake/vue-unity-webgl. This version of Unity uses a UnityLoader.js script to load the project in the browser. It needs to access some Module variables, but it is not able to access them.

Currently it puts out the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'compatibilitycheck' of undefined
>       at UnityLoader.js:2

Below is the Vue component:

```
<template>
<div class="Virtual Avatar">
    <canvas class="emscripten" id="canvas" oncontextmenu="event.preventDefault()" height="600px" width="960px"></canvas>
</div>
</template>
<script>

export default {    
    data: function () {
        return {
            Module: {
                TOTAL_MEMORY: 268435456,
                errorhandler: null,
                compatibilitycheck: null,
                backgroundColor: "#80858B",
                splashStyle: "Dark",
                dataUrl: "../../static/virtual-avatar/Release/virtual-avatar.data",
                codeUrl: "../../static/virtual-avatar/Release/virtual-avatar.js",
                asmUrl: "../../static/virtual-avatar/Release/virtual-avatar.asm.js",
                memUrl: "../../static/virtual-avatar/Release/virtual-avatar.mem",
            }
        }
    },
    created() {
        var Module = this.Module
        console.log(Module)

        let unityLoaderScript = document.createElement('script')
        unityLoaderScript.setAttribute('src', '../../static/virtual-avatar/Release/UnityLoader.js')
        document.head.appendChild(unityLoaderScript)

        let unityProgressScript = document.createElement('script')
        unityProgressScript.setAttribute('src', '../../static/virtual-avatar/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js')
        document.head.appendChild(unityProgressScript)

        let unityTextToSpeechScript = document.createElement('script')
        unityTextToSpeechScript.setAttribute('src', '../../static/virtual-avatar/TemplateData/textToSpeech.js')
            document.head.appendChild(unityTextToSpeechScript)
    }
}
```

Is there another way to add variables to Vue components? Or is there a better way to attach external scripts? And is an external script able to access such variables? Thanks in advance!